# How to detect which test case has failed?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcodebuild, xctest

I have around 300 test cases in my app and when I run them through terminal using with the following command

```
xcodebuild -project GiaPet.xcodeproj -scheme GiaPet -sdk iphonesimulator clean  build test
```

tests starts running and in the very end I get:

`** Test Failed ** and message says "Executed 219 tests, with 1 failure"`

And then I have to go through this huge log to know which test has failed.

Is there a better way to know which test case has failed?

Answer (score 0):

Have look at [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) or [xcpretty](https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty). Both of the tools have nice output.